# Magento, user logged in, dont show products categories, why?

Tags: magento, view, categories, product

i've problem with my magento.

Site working done, if i'm not logged user.
If i click on category (.../catalog/category/view/s/bundle/id/409/)
i show products correctly.

Now,
if i logged in, and click on category (.../catalog/category/view/s/bundle/id/409/)
i see this error:

```
    SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_sku`.`value` AS `sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=6 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='406'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '3' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '9'
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_sku` ON (`at_sku`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_sku`.`attribute_id` = '98') AND (`at_sku`.`store_id` = 0) ORDER BY `sku` asc LIMIT 30
```

this is trace: Trace:

```
#0 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#4 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#5 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#6 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(687): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#7 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1007): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...')
#8 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(831): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Observer.php(78): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1299): Mage_Review_Model_Observer->catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1274): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Review_Model_Observer), 'catalogBlockPro...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/Trace: /public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#13 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(163): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#14 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#15 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#17 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#18 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/em0028/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(63): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#19 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/xxx/...')
#20 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/em0028...')
#21 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#25 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#27 /home/xxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/em0028/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#28 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/xxx/...')
#29 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/em0028...')
#30 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#31 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#32 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#34 /home/xx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#35 /home/xx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#36 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#37 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#38 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#39 /home/xxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#40 /home/xxx/public_html/STORE.it/index.php(81): Mage::run('cuscinobiscotto', 'store')
#41 {main}
```

Why?

Comment: I don't see any error ..

Comment: My guess is that someone has left `var_dump()` with `die()` somewhere in the code.

Comment: Omg, and now how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use a Layout handle 'customer_logged_in' in Layout.xml and there you add a Second category List ...

Comment: Thanks Mischa! i dont find layout.xml i see in app/desing but there isn't this file.

Comment: you´ll propably find it in another Layout-XML...do a search in your project für <customer_logged_in> maybe you find that there is a category list added...